# When apply observer pattern an error occured

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have the following code:

```
class ISubscriber;
class News {
public:
    float getVersion() { return this->version; }
    void setVersion(float state) { this->version= state; this->notifyAllSubscribers(); }
    void attach(ISubscriber *observer) { this->subscribers.push_back(observer); }
    void notifyAllSubscribers() {
        for (vector<ISubscriber*>::iterator it = subscribers.begin(); it != subscribers.end(); it++){
            (*(*it)).update();
        }
    }
private:
    vector<ISubscriber*> subscribers;
    float version;
};

class ISubscriber {
public:
    News *news;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class Subscriber1 : public ISubscriber {
public:
    Subscriber1(News *news) { this->news = news; this->news->attach(this); }
    void update() override { cout << "Subscriber1: A new version of the newspaper has been launched (v" << this->news->getVersion() << ")" << endl; }

};

class Subscriber2 : public ISubscriber {
public:
    Subscriber2(News *news) { this->news = news; this->news->attach(this); }
    void update() override { cout << "Subscriber2: A new version of the newspaper has been launched (v" << this->news->getVersion() << ")" << endl; }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    News newspaper;
    newspaper.setVersion(2.1f);

    Subscriber1 sb1(&newspaper);
    Subscriber2 sb2(&newspaper);
    return 0;
}
```

But strange errors happened:

[image]

The first error points to this code `(*(*it)).update();` in `news` class.
Why that errors happened, what's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(*(*it)).update();` requires the type `ISubscriber` to be complete, just the forward declaration is not enough.

You could move the defnition of `ISubscriber` before the one of `News`, and give a forward declaration of `News` before that.

```
class News;
class ISubscriber {
public:
    News *news;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class News {
public:
    float getVersion() { return this->version; }
    void setVersion(float state) { this->version= state; this->notifyAllSubscribers(); }
    void attach(ISubscriber *observer) { this->subscribers.push_back(observer); }
    void notifyAllSubscribers() {
        for (vector<ISubscriber*>::iterator it = subscribers.begin(); it != subscribers.end(); it++){
            (*(*it)).update();
        }
    }
private:
    vector<ISubscriber*> subscribers;
    float version;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am still don't understand why it did not work in my own way but it worked when I changed the position of the `news` class and `ISubscriber` (I want to understand the idea)?

Comment: @LionKing `(*(*it)).update();` is trying to call the member function `update()` on `ISubscriber`, before that the compiler needs to see the definition of `ISubscriber`, otherwise it can't know whether `ISubscriber` contains such a member function. Note the position, defining `ISubscriber` afterwards won't work.